# Getting an ajax request to update a column in a SQL Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I am trying to get the current code to take the on or off value from the form and put it into an SQL database using a function call to a JS function that contains an AJAX request that then posts it to a PHP page that runs the actual query. I am not sure what I have done wrong and the API has been more confusing than helpful. I appreciate any help!

Current Page Code:

```
<?php require('../php/validation.php');?>
<?php require('../php/background.php');?>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['selectonoff'])){
    $_SESSION['onoff'] = $_POST['selectonoff'];
    $query = 'UPDATE onoff SET onoroff = $_POST["selectonoff"] WHERE ID = 1;';
    $update = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  }
     ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>User Settings Dropdown Menu</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/settings.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
      document.getElementById("selectonoff").value = '<?php echo $_SESSION['onoff'];?>';
}
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function rel(id)
  {
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: 'id='+id,
       url: "../php/update.php",
       cache: false,
       success: function(response)
       {
         alert("Record successfully updated");
       }
     });
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">
  <!-- <div id="wrap"> -->
    <br><br><br><br>
    <h1>Admin Settings Menu</h1>
      <form method="post" action="adminconfig.php">
        <p>Toggle BBQ Form</p>
        <select id="selectonoff" name="selectonoff" onchange="this.form.submit(); rel();">
          <option value="NONE">Select</option>
          <option value="ON">Toggle ON</option>
          <option value="OFF">Toggle OFF</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    <form action="../index.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Home" />
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script  src="../js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Current PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    require ('php/server.php');
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dedricks');
    if(!$db){
        die("Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $var = @$_POST['id'] ;
    $query = 'UPDATE onoff SET onoroff = $var WHERE ID = 1;';
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
?>
```

Comment: First of all `function rel(id)` has an argument  and onchange you used just `rel()` .. 2nd: What is the `id` which you pass it to php?? .. If the `id` if a select value then onchange use `rel(this.value)` instead of `rel()`

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections needed here.

**ERRORS**

1. You are not reading the value of the select control anywhere in your code that needs to be sent in the ajax call
2. `onchange` for the `selectonoff` list is trying to `submit` the `form` and at the same time calling `rel` function (without any parameter). It seems like it needs to trigger the ajax call when the `selectonoff` selection is changed.
3. The jquery needs to be added once either via cdn or from local directory
4. It needs to be added before the script tag in the head.

**TODO**

Remove `this.form.submit();` and `rel` from `onchange`. Rather remove the entire `onchange`

A code based on your page that is working and submitting the data to the php page is as below. You can make the changes according to your needs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Settings Dropdown Menu</title>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function rel(id){

          var formData = {"id": id};
          $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: formData,
           url: "../app/update.php",
           cache: false,
           success: function(response){
               console.log("response", response);
             alert("Record successfully updated");
           },
           error: function(error){
                console.log("error", error);
           }
         });
     }

     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#selectonoff").change(function(){
             var val = $("#selectonoff option:selected").val();
             rel(val);
         });
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <div id="wrap"> -->
    <br><br><br><br>
    <h1>Admin Settings Menu</h1>
    <form method="post" action="adminconfig.php">
        <p>Toggle BBQ Form</p>
        <select id="selectonoff" name="selectonoff">
            <option value="NONE">Select</option>
            <option value="ON">Toggle ON</option>
            <option value="OFF">Toggle OFF</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <form action="../index.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Home" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**NOTE**
I have now tested the above code to be working and submitting the ajax request to a php script.

Comment: I'm surprised I missed adding in the variable to be used in the function call but i changed it to try what you put up but that wasn't able to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you give some more info for example can you tell about the error you got?

Comment: See now the post ajax call need an object to be sent in for `data` attribute I have not tried this code myself.